# Save EntityType choice as string - Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have entity1 and entity2.

In the entity1's form, I am displaying a choice list where the options are comming from entity2.
I want to save the selected choice as string inside a column in entity1's table, but I dont want to create any relations between the tables.

How Should I do that?

```
class Entity1 {
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $historico;
}

class Entity2 {
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $description;
}
```

Entity1FormType.php

```
$builder->add('historico', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Entity2::class,
                'choice_label' => 'description',
                'choice_value' => 'description',
                'placeholder' => ''
            ]);
```

The choices display fine, but when I submit I get the following error:

```
Expected argument of type "string", "App\Entity\Entity2" given.
```

If I use 'mapped' => false, the input submit as null.

How do I convert the entity object to string?
Help a symfony noob :)

Comment: Hi Man, I sugget you to read this : I think it's what you need... Goog luck ! http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use mapped => false you have to fetch the data manually in your controller after the form is submitted.

so you will have something like this:

```
public function postYourFormAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity1 = new Entity1();
    $form = $this->createForm(Entity1Type::class $entity1);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entity1 = $form->getData;
        $historico = $form->get('historico')->getData();
        $entity1->setHistorico($historico);
        $em->persist($entity1);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach and now it gives me the following error: 
Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Entity1::setHistorico() must be of the type string, object given, called in 'file/path' on line 77, which I guess is the same error as before?

Comment: Then for example if you want to save the 'id' of historico in your entity:
$entity1->setHistorico($historico->getId());   or whatever property you may need

Comment: Ah, I get it now! Thank you Daniele, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with data transformers so you would not have to unmap fields.

Your form could be as below. Note the choice value getting the string

```
class OrderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function __construct(private ItemToStringTransformer $transformer)
    {
        $this->transformer = $transformer;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add('itemCode', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Item::class,
            'autocomplete' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'choice_value' => function (?Item $entity) {
                return $entity ? $entity->getCode() : '';
            },
            // validation message if the data transformer fails
            'invalid_message' => 'That is not a valid Item Code',
        ]);

        $builder->get('accountCode')->addModelTransformer($this->transformer);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
        // Configure your form options here
        ]);
    }
}
```

And then the data transformer can be as below

```
class ItemToStringTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function __construct(private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
    }

    //transforming item object to string
    public function reverseTransform($item): ?string
    {
        if (null === $item) {
            return null;
        }

        return $item->getCode();
    }

    // transforming string to item object
    public function transform($itemCode): ?Item
    {
    
        if (!$itemCode) {
            return null;
        }

        $item = $this->entityManager
            ->getRepository(Item::class)
            // query for the glCode with this id
            ->findOneBy(['code' => $itemCode])
        ;

        if (null === $item) {
            // causes a validation error
            // this message is not shown to the user
            // see the invalid_message option
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf('Item code "%s" does not exist!', $itemCode));
        }

        return $item;
    }
}
```

You can read further in the symfony documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html#example-2-transforming-an-issue-number-into-an-issue-entity